# Performance loss of a 32bit OS on a 64bit processor

Tags: 64-bit, operating-systems

I recently reinstalled my notebook, and my friend laughed at me because I didn't install the 64bit-version of vista instead of the 32bit one.

After which I wondered whether there was a great difference in performance with the 64 OS.

(I've always been sceptical about the 64bit version, because people used to tell me there were a lot of applications which didn't work anymore since they installed the 64bit version.)

So who can clear this up for me? :)

Comment: You need friends with a better sense of humour.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're doing computational intensive tasks then you won't notice a difference between the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of your OS. I am running Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit and haven't had a problem yet in terms of getting something to run. Windows does a great job at running 32-bit software.

Several years ago when Windows XP 64-bit came out there were lots of problems with software/drivers not running properly. However, much progress has been made since then.

Answer (score 1):

From a pure performance perspective, the answer will rely on the apps you're running. The 64-bit instructions are more efficient, but the memory pointers are larger, meaning less code will fit in cache. On average, the two effects cancel each other out, but there are cases where one or the other will dominate.

Since more people are still running 32-bit, the drivers for 32-bit will be easier to find and more thoroughly debugged.

Answer (score 1):

32-bit OS'es, in addition to not being able to use efficiently more than 4GiB of RAM, also can not efficiently `mmap()` files larger than 4GiB.  This last part comes up more often than you'd think.

Comment: Does anybody really needs to mmap >4GB at once? Any large file can be mapped by parts in 32-bit programme with mmap64(3) system call. So it is really no needs of expanding all your pointers TWICE for mmaping extra big files.

OS can be 64-bit while running a lot of 32-bit programmes.

Comment: @osgs Scientific applications, some language interpreters and all others that could benefit from overcommiting memory.

Answer (score 1):

Important:

I know this question is *old* but the answer needs updating. The short answer is *rather use an AMD64 (x86_64 or 64bit)*.

The Longer Answer (correcting some misconceptions in other answers):
Everyone here mentioned the advantage of 62bit systems as being able to use more than 4GiB RAM. Since PAE (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAE) was introduced into most kernels, 32bit system can handle more RAM just fine. I'm also advising anyone stumbling on this question that 32bit x86 is not "maintained" as well these days (ala 2015+). There's a lot of software that's written for AMD64 only. I think Ubuntu dropped 32bit last LTS, and Debian is one of the few that still supports it (because Debian supports even dead/dying platforms -- which 32bit x86 is.)
Also, consider that nearly every OS is multi-arch (both lib and lib32) so 32bit software works fine without a significant performance hit. 64bit software *cannot* run on a 32bit system, *but* 32bit software *can* on a 64bit system (provided the developers aren't like the PCSX2 team who expect the package maintainers to create their own 64bit fork or put up with it being 32bit-only /rant). Anyway, for better or worse, it's a consideration.

The Take Home: The situation is in reverse now. *64bit x86 is de facto now* and 32bit will become deprecated. While PAE allows 32bit machines to use more than 4GiB RAM, it's advisable you *use an AMD64 (x86_64, 64bit) OS* because your 32bit stuff will still run just fine, but so will 64bit stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with JustAnAnonUser_13249 that the answer is old, however none of the answers covers it enough.

As per title: `performance loss of a 32bit OS on a 64bit processor`:

- Assuming a windows setup (quite different answers for other OS’s)
- And a AMD 64 setup. (which is what Intel uses. Intel 64bit used to be Itanium)

First of, vista 32 bit will run just as fast on a 32 bit processor as on a 64 bit processor (in 32 bit mode). There is **no** performance loss here.

What your friend probably tried to say is “Why not use windows vista 64 bits and take advantage of the 64 bit CPU in your laptop?”.

In which case:

1. Drivers in 2009 probably were less stable on the windows platform. This is no longer the case. (actually, I suspect it is not the reverse)
2. The memory foot print of the OS and programs becomes larger. Cache hit ratios go down. This makes it **slower** to run 64 bits.
3. AMD 64 has many improvements over the old 32 bit setup. E.g. double the number of registers. This makes it faster.

In practise these last two point cancel each other.

There are reasons NOT to use an ancient 32 bit OS anymore though, examples:

1. Address space is limited to 4GiB. That is 4GiB minus reserved address space for PCI cards. (so a 4GiB RAM system with a 1GB graphics card might have less then 3GiB usuable.
2. Windows programs are limited to 2GiB max. Using PEA you can address more memory but you are still limited to 2GiB per program. (Read: You can open multiple 2GiB programs. E.g. three 2GiB programs. But not a single 5GiB one)
3. Drivers: Almost nobody uses 32 bit systems anymore. It might be hard to find a 32 bit driver instead of the normal one (which is quite different from 2009 when the question was posted).

> (I've always been sceptical about the 64bit version, because people used to tell me there were a lot of applications which didn't work anymore since they installed the 64bit version.)

User error. A 64 bit browser, a 64 bit plug -in, 64 bit java etc all work fine.

Trying to use a 64 bit browser and 32 bit java or the other way around o.t.o.h. is all sorts of fun.

> So who can clear this up for me? :)

I suspect you are not longer going to read this, but in case anyone hits this answer: Google this site. There are dozens of variations on this question.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have to address memory beyond the 4 GB threshold, you're perfectly fine with a 32-bit OS.

Comment: that is the case :) So I guess I didn't really make the wrong decision of choosing 32bit!

Answer (score 0):

For a notebook, which has likely less than 4 GB of memory, 64 bit Windows would be overkill. The smart move is to run 32 bit Windows, which also makes it more likely that all drivers work and that most software runs.

Specifically, on e a notebook, you might actually prefer 32 bit Windows' ability to run DOS games.

And yes, 32 bit Windows would actually be faster than 64 bit Windows on most notebook hardware.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have driver support I would have suggested 64 bit windows as well.  You can try it and see if your apps perform any differently. Generally it's been my experience that the 64 bit windows multitasks alot better.  I migrated a friend of mine who is a big gamer from 32 to 64 bit and he was able to go from haveing 2 WOW clients open (with framerate issues) to 4 with no issues.  Others have changed at my office have had no real difference in performance running office apps.

Answer (score -1):

Your friend is a *poor* techie. Unless you have more than 3GB of RAM, there's no reason to use 64bit, and your processor will handle 32bit just as well - there's no rule saying 32bit processors are better at 32bit tasks.

If you have more than 4GB of RAM, you should definitely be on 64bit, however, as a 32bit OS will only give you ~3.5gb to play around with out of that. Else, feel free to laugh right back as he faces slightly increased RAM usage from having 64bit pointers* instead of 32bit pointers, with no upside! (unless he has more than 4GB himself)

*A tiny increase, to be sure, but it's potentially DOUBLE the ram usage! In actuality it's barely perceptible, but he's not dealing in fact either :P

Comment: I'm still wondering about this one: I DO have 4GB RAM and you say the 32bit versions only use up to 3.5 GB's ... So that means I don't use half a gig of my memory, right? (But I also think it's not worth it to reinstall my whole system a 2nd time for half a gig extra)

Comment: Well, depending on what other hardware you have installed, pretty much. A 32bit OS can only address 4GB of memory, and this includes your RAM, your graphics card's GRAM, your soundcard's memory, and so on. It's not worth reformatting over, but it's worth keeping in mind.